# How to dispatch another action from an action and dispatch another action in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuex

In Vuex action, we have the following implementation.

```
async actionA({ commit, dispatch }) {
  const data = this.$axios.$get(`/apiUrl`)
  await Promise.all([
    dispatch('actionB', { data: data }),
    dispatch('actionOthers'),
  ]).then(() => {
    commit('mutationA', data)
  })
}

async actionB({ commit, dispatch }, { data }) {
  await this.$axios.$get('/apiUrl', { params: data }).then(res => {
    if (res.length === 0) {
      dispatch('actionC', { data: data })
    }
    commit('mutationB', res)
  })
}

async actionC({ commit, dispatch }, { data }) {
  await this.$axios.$get('/anotherUrl', { params: data }).then(res => {
    commit('mutationC', res)
  })
}
```

Dispatch `actionB` from`actionA` and dispatch `actionC` from`actionB` depending on the result of `actionB`.
However, `actionA` will be resolved before`actionC` completes.

How should I cope with such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid that actionA resolves before actionC completes, you need to await on the dispatch actionC action.

You need to rewrite your actionB like this:

```
async actionB({ commit, dispatch }, { data }) {
    const res = await this.$axios.$get('/apiUrl', { params: data })
    if (res.length === 0) {
        await dispatch('actionC', { data: data })
    }
    commit('mutationB', res)
}
```